# Using INDIRECT with sheet names taken from a range

Tags: google-sheets

This formula I created worked in Excel:

`=ROUNDUP(SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(INDIRECT("'"&$N$5:$N$41&"'!A6:A100"),A5,INDIRECT("'"&$N$5:$N$41&"'!C6:C1000"))),0)`

This formula is in my main sheet, 'Summary'.

I populated a list of sheet names in a work book and put it in column N in 'Summary'. If the names in my main sheet `A6:A100` match those in the other sheets then SUM all the numbers in column `C6:C1000` for each sheet (based on the sheetname).

For some reason it is only taking the number from the first sheet on my list of sheet names.

Could anyone help with this please?

Comment: The formula contain  C1000 but later you said C100. Which one is correct?

Comment: C1000 because assuming the list will keep going

Comment: the size of array parameters should match , so change A100 to A1000

Comment: it is still only pulling from the first sheet of the workbook. I need it to pull from all of the sheets in the workbook